# using shell in awk snippet

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a problem about shell and awk while using them nested. I have a shell script code that prints the processes to a file then I want to read them with awk and when I find a process with special condition (for ex: the process' start hour is 10:00) I want to copy it to another file. However I couldn't make it. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh

processes=` ps aux > processes.txt `

awk 'BEGIN {FS = " ";}
{
    if (some statement)
    {
        temp = $0 // I want to copy all the line to another file
        " temp >> anotherfile.txt " // Here i want to use "temp" as shell veriable but i couldn't do it
   }
}
END {}' processes.txt
```

Can anyone show me a hint so maybe I can figure out something. Thanks.

Comment: You need to learn some shell and ask fundamentals as neither the shell nor the awk in your script make any sense at all. I recommend the books Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson and Effective Awk Programming by Arnold Robbins.

Answer (score 2):

```
ps aux | awk '$9=="10:00"' >>anotherfile.txt
```